# Dynamic CSS selector in Angular.js app

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am working on an Angular.js app with a plane view that contains objects. 
Each time when the user drags an item from the left menu bar on to the middle of the screen, a new object is initiated.

The CSS selector of each item looks like this:

```
  #drag-item-0

   #drag-item-1

   #drag-item-2
```

etc.

So basically, each instation of an object leeds to an new CSS selector. I need to give each object different CSS styling, but I don´t know, how the corresponding CSS selector would look like. Any help or hints would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you use css classes or ng-style?

Answer (score 0):

If those are children elements of a, let's say `<div Id="elid"><\div>` you could use the `nth-child(pos)` where `pos` is the children element position.

Like `#elid:nth-child(2)` to get the second children element of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can target odd and even rows so that new rows are distinctive when added:

```
div:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
div:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

You could also set up a repeater with SASS/LESS to target n number of objects, like this:

```
@iterations: 10;

.span-loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
                #drag-item-@{i} {
                    background: rbga(@i * 10, 25,25,1);
                }

            .span-loop(@i - 1);
        }

        .span-loop (@iterations);*/
```

Which would create css selectors for #drag-item-0 through to #drag-item-10